# Parsing with MessageFormat: Is there a way to force greedy matching, or to require that the entire input be matched?

Tags: java, string-formatting, string-parsing, greedy, messageformat

Or: is there a another utility capable of both [formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format-java.lang.Object-) strings and [parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#parseObject-java.lang.String-) strings (using the same object!) that can achieve this?

Suppose you have a directory full of audio files in `.au` format with names following the pattern `country.code.XX.au`.  We might like to format and parse the significant parts of these filenames using a `MessageFormat` with pattern `country.{0}.au`.

But consider this demo:

```
public class MessageFormatExercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        java.text.Format f = new java.text.MessageFormat("country.{0}.au");

        // String formatting; prints "country.code.us.au" and "country.code.au.au" respectively
        System.out.println(f.format(new Object[]{"code.us"}));
        System.out.println(f.format(new Object[]{"code.au"}));

        // String parsing; prints "code.us" and "code" respectively (not "code.au"!)
        System.out.println(((Object[]) f.parseObject("country.code.us.au"))[0]);
        System.out.println(((Object[]) f.parseObject("country.code.au.au"))[0]);
    }
}
```

The parse results are not consistent.  In some cases we get `code.us` or `code.gb` but in the case of Australia we get simply `code`.

Comment: The modernized `com.ibm.icu.text.MessageFormat` with named template parameters and saner quoting rules exhibits the same behavior, yielding `code` rather than `code.au`